# Using JQuery to get a JSON Object from an encrypted source

Tags: jquery, json, https

I have access to two different servers.  Server #1 has a lot of sensitive information.  I programmed it to be able to format that information as JSON objects.  All information on server #1 is encrypted (https://)

I programmed a site on server #2 (using JQuery).  It basically does this:

```
var URL = 'https://sensitiveInfo.json' 

$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
...
});
```

However, server #2 cannot seem to access the JSON object from my encrypted server #1.  If I encrypt server #2 (make it https:// instead of http://) will that allow it to handle the encrypted information?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will. Either way, it can't hurt to make communications to/from server #2 encrypted as well.

Answer (score 2):

No idea what you are talking about but as long as you don't violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you will be able to send AJAX requests. But if you change the port you violate this policy. For example if you try to send an AJAX request to an HTTPS from a page serverd from HTTP this won't work.

The best way to ensure you are not violating this policy is to use relative urls:

```
var URL = '/sensitiveInfo.json' 
$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is an alternative to circumvent this browser restriction.

Comment: The relative URL wouldn't work because server #1 can ONLY be accessed via https:// and server #2 can only be accessed via http://, but I am looking at JSONP and that seems like it will be able to solve the problem